# Problems with matplotlib blitted cursor embeded in PyQt6 gui

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mouse-cursor, pyqt6, matplotlib-widget

I´m currently developing a software to process spectroscopic data using python. I´m using PyQt6 to design the gui and matplotlib to plot the data. To simplify the data selection I added a cursor widget from matplotlib to the axes. For improved performace I used the blitting mode.

Here´s a minimal code example:

```
# Import packages
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


# Main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize QMainWindow
        super().__init__()
        # Get MplWidget
        self.mpl_widget = MplWidget()
        # Set MplWidget as central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mpl_widget)
        # Create axes
        self.ax = self.mpl_widget.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # Reference Cursor
        self.cursor = Cursor(self.ax, useblit=True)
        # Plot some random stuff
        x, y = np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100)
        self.ax.scatter(x, y)
        # Show app
        self.show()


# MplCanvas
class MplWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Initialize QWidget
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Create canvas
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        # Set constrained layout
        self.canvas.figure.set_constrained_layout(True)
        # Create layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        # Add canvas
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        # Set layout
        self.setLayout(layout)


# Initialize app
app = QApplication([])
UI = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Generally everything works fine, the cursor appears when hovering the axis and dissapears when leaving it, but when the mouse enters the axis, the whole axis content moves a little bit. Sometimes the figure edges also change their colors, e.g. from black to gray.

Here are two gifs to explain the phenomenon:

[image: Minimal example]

[image: Real application]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: i did a quick check with pyqt5 since I don't have qt6 installed at the moment (just changed first input to `from PyQt5.`) and I don't get the issues you're describing... maybe its related to qt6?

Comment: I think so too. The problem only appears in PyQt6, not in PyQt5.